# How to parallelize polars partition_by result dataframes processing in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, parallel-processing, python-polars

I have polars Data Frame. Also I have a complex function of processing parts of this df.

```
def processing_df(df):
    ...
    ...
    return result # np.array for example

df_gr = df_sourse.partition_by(groups="group_col", maintain_order=True)

results = []
for df in df_gr:
    res = processing_df(df)
    results.append(res)
```

Is it possible to parallelize the processing of a list of dataframes received from a partition? Taking into account the fact that polars already parallelizes calculations, but as I understand it in this context, polars will not parallelize calculations between processing individual dataframes from the list. I would like to speed up dataframe processing.

P.S. I tried use [this approaches](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/), but processes were not running.

Comment: You could use a [process pool](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/multiprocessing.html#combining-polars-with-pythons-multiprocessing) e.g. `results = pool.map(processing_df, df_gr)` - what does your function do exactly? Perhaps it could be implemented with Polars expressions? Then you could use `.groupby().agg()` instead allowing polars to do the parallelization.